# How to upload and execute a java program remotelly from IDE

Tags: java, remote-server

Are there any easy way to run a java code from the IDE (Intellij for example) on a remote machine (without jar)?

I am trying to execute the code that I am developing in a remote machine, without package and upload a JAR every time that i compiled the code. The idea would be to run the code on a remote machine in a simple way and see the result in the IDE.

Summary: 
The main idera is execute the program as a normal script in another machine and be trasparent to developer. Execution looks normal but the code are being executed on another machine.

This is an exploratory question because im not find any similar solution.

Comment: I mean, some IDE support remote debugging like [netbeans](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/netbeans-the-definitive/0596002807/ch04s08.html); but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking.  Are you looking for continuous integration?

Comment: An IDE could do it (internally it creates the artifacts and deploys it to a remote server). For instance I've done this using IntelliJ IDEA and Tomcat

Comment: I find a native solution without remote GUI connection to another machine (another machine have not GUI) –

Answer (score 1):

Without having a better idea of the big picture, I'd say that this may not be something that IDEs are likely to make easy for you.

There are possibilities:

- Most IDEs support plugins and custom tool integration. You could set up automation to transfer the files and invoke them remotely.  You'd basically be doing all the work.
- You could use something like a remote disk mount or an editor with remote file editing support to store the files on the remote server and then modify them locally and run them remotely using a remote shell.
- You could use some sort of cloud IDE setup that would allow you to edit the files that are hosted on the remote server and invoke them. Tools like this exist, although you'd have to install things and it might be more work than the other options here.
- If the remote server is a web application server (e.g. Tomcat), you could certainly have your IDE deploy a WAR to the remote server and then invoke it over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Your idea is similar to package and upload a JAR to the system and execute it from command line (SSH) The idea would be use a more transparent execution way. Something similar to remote debug but focused on remote execution

Comment: Sure -- something like a remote REPL. Java and Java IDEs are not really designed to make that easy for you, but that doesn't mean you can't set something up that does that, but you'll probably have to do a lot of the work yourself.